# Does Nunit TestCase attribute with Result property work incorrect?

Tags: nunit, resharper, resharper-6.0

So, I wrote next "test" test :-) for Nunit 2.6 (use 2.6.0.12035 ver.)

```
    [TestCase(1, 2, Result = 3)]
    [TestCase(3, 4, Result = 7)]
    [TestCase(5, 6, Result = 11)]
    public int Add_Test(int a, int b)
    {
        return a - b;
    }
```

Next, I run it with Resharper 6.1.37.86. Resharper shows that all three test are passed.
Than I try to run test with nunit GUI - nunit.exe. Tests fall with strange error message: "Method has non-void return value".
In fact all tests should fail with unexpected value of result.
Does this feature work incorrect or I do smth. wrong?
By the way, next I try do without set Result property and it works perfect with both runners:

```
    [TestCase(1, 2, 3)]
    [TestCase(3, 4, 7)]
    [TestCase(5, 6, 11)]
    public void Add_Test1(int a, int b, int result)
    {
        Assert.AreEqual(result, a - b);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I get the same problem with NUnit 2.6.0.12035, whether I use NUnit.exe or NUnit-console.exe.

Your example works fine using NUnit.exe 2.5.10.  (My guess is that Resharper is using NUnit 2.5.10 and so the test passes.)

I [reported the issue](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/nunit-discuss/Y-5UgAPXzh0) to the NUnit discussion group.

**Edit:**  My test assembly was referencing the 2.5.10 version of *NUnit.framework.dll*.  If I switch to use the 2.6.0.12035 version, the test works as expected with both *NUnit.exe* and *NUnit-console.exe*.  I'll bet your issue is the same.

**Edit 2:**  It has been submitted as a bug and [fixed in the next release](https://bugs.launchpad.net/nunitv2/+bug/935952). The test runners in 2.6 will no longer cause an error if your unit test library links to an older version of *Nunit.framework.dll*.